# Render component vue js into nav tab

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with render component (courses), when i want click in case "undergraduate" but the componenent renders in the last tab panel... help me please!, any idea how solve this problem? thanks.

in the image have the issue render only in the last nav tab [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp4Dh.png)

here my code

Html

```
<div id="ofert" class="row py-4">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <div class="row">            
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 p-0">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-column nav-ga-pills" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" @@click.prevent="navClick" data-graduation="Undergraduate" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#undergraduate" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">undergraduate</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" @@click.prevent="navClick" data-graduation="Postgraduate" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#postgraduate" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">oosgraduate</a>
                    </li>                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="undergraduate" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">
                <courses ref="courses" :static=`image`></courses>          
                
            </div >
            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="postgraduate" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">
                <courses ref="courses" :static=`image`></courses>                
                
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

parent

```
import courses from '../components/microspecial/ofert.vue'



new Vue({
    el: '#ofert',
    components: { courses },
    data() {
        return {
            graduationlevel: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        navClick(e) {
            this.graduationlevel = e.currentTarget.dataset.graduation;
            this.$refs.courses.showData(this.graduationlevel);
        }
    }
});
```

child

```
<template>    
   <div class="row bg-light">
       <div v-for="item in courses" class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 p-4 border-bottom">
           <div class="row ga-i-box-oferta">
               <div class="col-md-12 mb-2 ga-tittle-oferta">
                   <h2>{{item.Name}}</h2>
               </div>
               <div class="d-none d-lg-block col-md-5">
                   <div><img class="border" :src="url +`/repository/microspecial/courses/` + item.Id + `.png`" alt="" width="130" /></div>
               </div>
               <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-7 ga-i-box-oferta-info">
                   <i class="fas fa-barcode"></i><span>Snies: {{item.Snies}}</span><br>
                   <i class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher"></i><span>{{item.MethodologyName}}</span><br />
                   <i class="fas fa-user-graduate"></i><span>{{item.Title}} </span>
                   <div class="ga-i-box-btn">
                       <a href="" id="getMoreInformation" role="button" data-id="item.Id" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalOferta">Más información <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
   export default {
       props: ['static'],
       data() {
           return {
               courses: [],
               url: this.static
           }
       },        
       methods: {
           showData(graduationLevel) {
               this.courses = [];
               fetch(`/MicroSpecial/GetCourses?graduationLevel=${graduationLevel}`)
                   .then(respon => respon.json())
                   .then(response => {
                       this.courses = response;
                   })
                   .catch(response => {
                   })
              
           }
       }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: In your case, you uses duplicated `ref=courses`, so the first one will be overwritten by second `ref`. so uses different `ref` name or avoid using `ref`. I don't think you really need to use **ref** in your case. Because I don't see any codes manipulate the DOM directly in showData.

Comment: @Sphinx thank you so much, I saw this error and changed ref